# envio de variable por $_GET

Tags: javascript

quisiera abrir otro enlace pasando parametros por la URL.
Al hacer click en un boton de una tabla de bootstrap capturo un valor y quiero abrir otra pagina en la cual pueda recibir ese valor.
desde ya muchas gracias y dejo el codigo que no logro hacerlo funcionar.

```
 var obtener_id_comprar= function(tbody, table){
        $(tbody).on("click", "button.comprar", function(e){
            var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
            var idcompra = $("#idcompra").val( data.idmb );
            $dati=(data.idmb);
            console.log($dati);
            location.href="indexcompra.php?var=$dati"                   
    
          });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Substituye el `location.href` por:

```
window.open('https://www.webdestino?parametro=valor' ,'_blank')
```

El parámetro `_blank` sirve para decirle que lo haga en una ventana nueva.

Mas info o ejemplos -> ver en [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)